# Выдает некорректные данные при комопиляции

Tags: c++

Задание: Даны две неубывающие последовательности A и B, образовать из них новую неубывающую последовательность, сортировку использовать нельзя.

Проблема:Выдает минимально возможные числа в данном типе данных в последних двух значениях новой последовательности

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int size_A = 4;
    const int size_B = 4;
    const int size_C = size_A + size_B;
    double A[size_A];
    double B[size_B];
    double C[size_C];
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Массив A:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
    {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    cout << "Массив B:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_B; i++)
    {
        cin >> B[i];
    }
    int b = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a <= size_A; a++)   
    {   
        while (b < size_B)
        {
            if (A[a] < B[b]) { C[n] = A[a]; n++; break; }
            else { C[n] = B[b]; n++; b++; }
        }
    }
    cout << "Массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size_C; i++)
    {
        cout << C[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему в заголовке написано "выдает при компиляции", если по вашему описанию видно, что проблема возникает при выполнении?

Comment: Потому что я дурачок и не разбираюсь в терминологии)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея реализации правильная, хоть и несколько неэлегантно записанная. Однако такой цикл

```
for (int a = 0; a <= size_A; a++)
```

будет в вашем варианте приводить к доступу за пределы массива `A` при `a == size_A`. Отсюда и возникает мусор (ваши "минимально возможные числа").

- Либо внутри цикла надо учитывать, что возможно `a == size_A`

  ```
  int n = 0;
  int b = 0;
  for (int a = 0; a <= size_A; a++)   
  {   
      while (b < size_B)
      {
          if (a < size_A && A[a] < B[b]) { C[n] = A[a]; n++; break; }
          else { C[n] = B[b]; n++; b++; }
      }
  }
  ```
- Либо все таки итерировать только пока `a < size_A`, но тогда уже после этого цикла необходимо докопировать возможный "хвост" массива `B`

  ```
  int n = 0;
  int b = 0;
  for (int a = 0; a < size_A; a++)   
  {   
      while (b < size_B)
      {
          if (A[a] < B[b]) { C[n] = A[a]; n++; break; }
          else { C[n] = B[b]; n++; b++; }
      }
  }

  while (b < size_B)
  {
    C[n] = B[b]; n++; b++;
  }
  ```

Comment: Спасибо помогло докопирование хвоста массива B) Большое спасибо, четыре часа мучался

Comment: @Карен Георгиевский: Если вы просто добавили в ваш исходный вариант "докопирование хвоста массива B", но при этом не исправили цикл, то работать правильно ваш код не будет.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду условие в цикле for? Я его исправил

Comment: @Карен Георгиевский: Тогда все нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько странное слияние. Почему это a сравнивается с размером итога?

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int n = 0;
while (a < size_A && b < size_B) {
      if (A[a] <= B[b]) 
           C[n++] = A[a++];
      else 
           C[n++] = B[b++];
}
```

Но после этого могут остаться неизрасходованные элементы из одного или другого массива

```
while (a < size_A)
     C[n++] = A[a++];
while (b < size_B)
     C[n++] = B[b++];
```

Comment: Надо не просто их объединить, но и упорядочить
Типа из A={2,3,4} и B={1,5,6,} должно получиться C={1,2,3,4,5,6}

Comment: Если они оба были упорядочены: `Даны две неубывающие последовательности`, объединение тоже будет упорядочено.